# How can flash open a port to listen for server requests?

Tags: flash, networking

Is it possible for flash to open ports to listen for messages from the remote server? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, Flash cannot currently do this. However AIR applications, which can be made from Flash, can do this as of version 2.0, using the [ServerSocket](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform//reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/ServerSocket.html?allClasses=1) class.

Comment: This is absolutely correct. And seeing what a major potential security issue this could is, I doubt it will ever be implemented.

Comment: Where's the "how" part?  A small sample would be nice, I can't find an example of how the ServerSocket class is correctly used.